# Setting Auto Layout constraints of IBOutlet in code

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

If I have a UILabel that is an IBOutlet, why can't I just set its Auto Layout constraints in code without also having to set at least one constraint in Storyboard?

For example, say I have an IBOutlet UILabel that has no constraints set in storyboard, and I try to center it in superview:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.label.centerInSuperview()
}
```

Then I have a UIView extension for handling the auto layout code as follows:

```
extension UIView {

    func centerInSuperview() {
        self.centerVerticallyInSuperview()
        self.centerHorizontallyInSuperview()
    }

    func centerVerticallyInSuperview() {
        self.superview?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.superview,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 0))
    }

    func centerHorizontallyInSuperview() {
        self.superview?.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: self,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
            relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
            toItem: self.superview,
            attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 0))
    }

}
```

The above code works fine if the UILabel is created from code:

```
var label = UILabel()
label.text = "Label"
self.view.addSubview(label)
label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
label.centerInSuperview()
```

But if the UILabel is an outlet with no constraints set in storyboard it doesn't work. Curiously if the outlet has one random constraint set in storyboard (like top space to superview), then it also works.

Comment: Are you calling `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` on the UI element you placed on storyboard?  Or *just* calling your `centerInSuperview()` ?

Comment: @nhgrif I have tried it with and without the setTranslates call. Neither work.

Comment: That's because the system adds constraints for you if you don't, and those constraints will conflict with yours. Look what it says under "constraints" in the Size Inspector for a view that you haven't added constraints for.

Comment: @rdelmar does that mean I need to remove all constraints before setting my own in code? When I look in Size Inspector for the label that I haven't added constraints for it says "The selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view."

Comment: First, I would say why bother adding the view in IB if you're not going to add constraints; just create it in code. If you really want to add it in IB, then add your own constraints, and check the "remove at build time" box when you edit the constraint.

Comment: @rdelmar solid point. I was thinking of a case where the constraints would dynamically change, but even then they could be initially set in storyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a storyboard or NIB has auto layout enabled for it, Xcode will not allow a view to lack constraints. Select the view and bring up the Size inspector. You will see a note to the effect that "The selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view."

In general, Xcode will provide constraints to eliminate ambiguity in the layout.

You can work around this by adding sufficient constraints to the view but marking them as placeholders (remove at build time). This will leave the view without constraints.

You could also add constraints, set up outlets to the constraints, and remove them programmatically before adding other constraints.